# Koha installation from git

Tags: server, 22.04

Hi i am trying to install koha software in by ubuntu machine from koha git repository.

make test command fails which says koha-dev directory not found.I couldnot found the folder in my directory, the path ins mentioned in makefile also.

```
Koha's files have now been installed.

In order to use Koha's command-line batch jobs,
you should set the following environment variables:

export KOHA_CONF=/home/{your user name}/koha-dev/etc/koha-conf.xml
export PERL5LIB=/home/{your user name}/kohaclone
```

I am following the official tutorial of koha named "Koha on ubuntu - git" .But not working for me. How to fix this?

Comment: "not working" is a poor problem description. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: i would like to know whether the installation of koha is possible in ubuntu 22.04, i have tried installing the official documentation cloning  the app to ubuntu 22.04 but installation failing..

Comment: Following [this](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_git)? Is obsolete